# Python+Selenium. Can't locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've implemented the script using Python and selenium to click on the ads.
But now this script is not working.
 Unable to find element on the page.
 Please help me to correct the script. Thank you!
[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://rutracker.ignn.ru')
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@class,"tblock_")]'))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'tmozs.com')]").click()
time.sleep(10)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Please include error in the question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python\test3.py", line 5, in <module>
 browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@class,"tblock_")]'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute

Comment: self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //iframe[starts-with(@class,"tblock_")]

Comment: Andrew i checked the site can you possibly tell where is the iframe with class tblock_

Comment: Rajan Chahan Earlier there was such a structure. There was a frame and its reference. But now apparently have changed the structure of advertising announcements. I need to make a click on one of the 3 adds. How to do it under the new block structure adds?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wait some time until required `iframe` appears in `DOM` before switch to it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "//tmozs.com/")]')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You can use the below code block to click on the ad at the top left corner:

> I have exclusively used `time.sleep()` to reduce the time in preparing this solution. All the `time.sleep()` can be replaced by **`Explicit Wait`**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('http://rutracker.ignn.ru')
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'tmozs.com/jsonp.php')]"))
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='feed-inner']/div[@class='feed-cell'][1]/a[@class='feed-cell-inner']/div[@class='teaser']/table[@class='teaser-inner']//img[contains(@src,'in.ogoyj.com')]").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @AndrewF. Did you get a chance to check out my Answer? Thanks