# Selenium+Python. How click this link?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please tell me, how i can click this link with Python+Selenium?

HTML:
[image]

SCRIPT(but not working):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://rutracker.ignn.ru')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'tmozs.com')]").click()
browser.quit()
```

Comment: There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095549/pythonselenium-cant-locate-element/45095830#45095830) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095549/pythonselenium-cant-locate-element) which can help to resolve the current issue

Comment: @Andersson Which one?

Comment: @DebanjanB, Links provided in comment

Comment: @Andersson Got it :) I didn't see the previous Question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

First you need to switch to the `frame`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('http://rutracker.ignn.ru')
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'tmozs.com/jsonp.php')]"))
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='feed-inner']/div[@class='feed-cell'][1]/a[@class='feed-cell-inner' and contains(@href,'http://tmozs.com/info.php?')]").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

> PS: You may consider to induce **`ExplicitWait`** instead of `time.sleep()` after switching to the frame for the elements to be visible/clickable.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[@class='feed-cell-inner' and contains(@href,'http://tmozs.com/info.php?')]

Comment: @AndrewF. Check my updated Answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: DebanjanB Yes!! It works!! Thank you very much! Have a nice day and weekends!

Comment: @Andrew F. Great news !!! Glad to be able to help you. Upvote the Answer if it was useful to you. Thanks

Comment: DebanjanB Hello friend! I try this script to click this link on other site. But no errors and no clicking =( ds.ignn.ru

Comment: @Andrew F. This `xpath` is for this specific element only. Other element will have a delta different `xpath`. We all know that each and every element is identified through unique `xpayh` only? Right?

Comment: DebanjanB Ad units in its structure the same on both sites. If Python could not find the element then it would be an error in the logs. But there are no errors..

Comment: @Andrew F. Observe your Question, in your script you did `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'tmozs.com')]").click()`
 which will always click on a **single** element. What happens will entirely depend on what is written in the `onClick()` event of that element. To click on all the links we will have to find (using `find_elements_by_xpath`) for a pattern of the `xpaths`, store them in a `List` and click on them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this XPATH :-  `//div[@class="feed-cell"]/a[@class="feed-cell-inner"]`

or `//a[@class="feed-cell-inner" or contains(@href,"http://tmozs.com") ]`

Comment: Can you try this out //div/a[@class="feed-cell-inner" and @herf='xyz.com']